# not able to add image to tab bar item react navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

# i am trying to add image to tab bar item but not able to load in react navigation #

##  i am referring https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1205#issuecomment-296708338  ##

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import ScreenOne from './ScreenOne';
import Screentwo from './Screentwo';
import Preferences from './Preferences';




const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
  Home: {
    screen : ScreenOne,
    navigationOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      tabBarIcon: <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }} source={require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png'
      )}/>,
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: '#00000',
      inactiveTintColor: '#000000'
    }
  },
  Settings: Screentwo,
  Preference: Preferences
},
{  
  initialRouteName: "Home"
}
);


export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

###  expecting to show image in tab bar item and hide tab bar label###

Comment: Try returning it doing `tabBarIcon: () => <Image/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tabBarIcon**

> React Element or a function that given `{ focused: boolean,
>   horizontal: boolean, tintColor: string }` returns a React.Node, to
>   display in the tab bar. `horizontal` is `true` when the device is in
>   landscape and `false` when portrait. The icon is re-rendered whenever
>   the device orientation changes.

**Usage**

```js
 {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor, image }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let imagepath;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          imagepath = require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png');
        } else if (routeName === "Settings") {
          imagepath = require('../images/Settings.png');
        } else if (routeName === "Preference") {
          imagepath = require('../images/Preference.png');
        }
        return (
          <Image
            style={{ width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: "stretch" }}
            source={imagepath}
          />
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Nativebase 
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#footer-tabs-icon-headref

import { Container, Header, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

```
<Footer>
      <FooterTab>
        <Button>
          <Icon name="apps" />
        </Button>
        <Button>
          <Icon name="camera" />
        </Button>
        <Button active>
          <Icon active name="navigate" />
        </Button>
        <Button>
          <Icon name="person" />
        </Button>
      </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
```